# AJAX to Google Forms works everytime in Chrome but only occasionally in FF and IE11

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-forms

I'm having a bit of an issue with using my AJAX code that posts to a google form, which I have developed from this site: https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/Send+data+to+Google+docs+using+a+web+form+and+AJAX

Basically I have constructed a webpage that collects some data in a form.  When the user clicks on the "next" button it runs through some JQuery that launches the following function:

```
function postQuToGoogle() {
    var pathclick = $('#text').val();
    var tasknumber = $('#taskno').text();
    var identifier = $('#ident').val();
    var duration = $('#timediff').val();
    var button = press;
    var treename = TestName;

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/......",
            data: { "entry.1507891248": pathclick,
                    "entry.2057302526": tasknumber,
                    "entry.1920694157": identifier,
                    "entry.900973756": treename,
                    "entry.706969357": button,
                    "entry.647049842": duration             
                     },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "jsonp",
        });
}
```

When I run it on Chrome it posts to the Google form every time.  When I run it on IE11 or FF (57) it only works some of the time.

I'm pretty new at coding JS and AJAX so have only learnt from what I have read on the internet.

I have run it through all three browsers with the console open to check for errors. They come up with the following every time:

Chrome's error:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://docs.google.com/forms/.....' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Firefox's errors:

> The resource from “https://docs.google.com/forms/.....” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).[Learn More]  (unknown)
>
> Loading failed for the  with source “https://docs.google.com/forms/....”.

IE11's error:

> Script from https://docs.google.com/forms/..... was blocked due to mime type mismatch

Any ideas on why Chrome does it every time but the other browsers appear to be a bit more choosy? And if there is a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I wasn't giving enough time for the Ajax to do it's thing.

In the main site code the postQuToGoogle function is called and then the browser is redirected to the next page.

I have now built in a two second delay after the submit button is pressed.The process goes like this now:

1. User presses submit button
2. Loader is faded in
3. postQuToGoogle is called
4. setTimeout is used to hold the page for two seconds
5. After two seconds the browser is directed to the next page

   ```
   function loaderIn(){
     $("#loader-wrapper").fadeIn("slow");}


   $("#surveypost").click(function(){
    loaderIn();
    postToGoogle();
    setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.href = "instructions.html";
    },2000);
   });
   ```